# why this MySQL SELECT doesn't include the right dates?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, select, conditional-statements

The main problem is, that I have stored in database *datetime* , not the date (what I need). Ok never mind.

I have thousands of reports stored each day.

I need to LEFT by 10 my datetime_view (to cut the time) and everything's fine. Except this. I'm trying to figure out why do I have to put in the condition + one day from the future? Otherwise it won't search what I want.

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(datetime_view,10),
    count(type) 
        FROM reports 
            WHERE 
        type IN (1,2,5) 
            AND 
        datetime_view>='2012-10-28' 
            AND
        datetime_view<='2012-11-04' 
            group by LEFT(datetime_view,10);
```

You can see I must search from the future. Why??

It gives me an output from 28.10 to 3.11 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use string operations on date/time values. MySQL has a [huge set of functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for date/time manipulation. Try

```
GROUP BY DATE(datetime_view)
```

instead, which will extract only the date portion of the datetime field. Your string operation is not y10k compliant. Using the date() function is.

As for your `plus one day`, consider how the comparisons are done: A plain date value, when used in date/time comparisons, has an implicit `00:00:00` time value attached to it, e.g. all dates have a time of "midnight".

Answer (score 1):

i think it's better to use `DATE(datetime_view)` to cut the time instead of `LEFT(datetime_view,10)`, also on the where condition:

```
DATE(datetime_view) <= '2012-11-03'
```